# using saved sklearn model to make prediction

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have a saved logistic regression model which I trained with training data and saved using joblib. I am trying to load this model in a different script, pass it new data and make a prediction based on the new data.

I am getting the following error "sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: CountVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted." Do I need to fit the data again ? I would have thought that the point of being able to save the model would be to not have to do this.

The code I am using is below excluding the data cleaning section. Any help to get the prediction to work would be appreciated.

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(latest_tweets,columns=['text'])
new_df.to_csv('new_tweet.csv',encoding='utf-8')
csv = 'new_tweet.csv'

latest_df = pd.read_csv(csv)
latest_df.dropna(inplace=True)
latest_df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
new_x = latest_df.text

loaded_model = joblib.load("finalized_mode.sav")

tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
cvec = CountVectorizer()
x_val_vec = cvec.transform(new_x)
X_val_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(x_val_vec)

result = loaded_model.predict(X_val_tfidf)
print (result)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your training part have 3 parts which are fitting the data:

- `CountVectorizer`: Learns the vocabulary of the training data and returns counts
- `TfidfTransformer`: Learns the counts of the vocabulary from previous part, and returns tfidf
- `LogisticRegression`: Learns the coefficients for features for optimum classification performance.

Since each part is learning something about the data and using it to output the transformed data, you need to have all 3 parts while testing on new data. But you are only saving the `lr` with joblib, so the other two are lost and with it is lost the training data vocabulary and count.

Now in your testing part, you are initializing new `CountVectorizer` and `TfidfTransformer`, and calling `fit()` (`fit_transform()`), which will learn the vocabulary only from this new data. So the words will be less than the training words. But then you loaded the previously saved LR model, which expects the data according to features like training data. Hence this error:

```
ValueError: X has 130 features per sample; expecting 223086
```

What you need to do is this:

## During training:

```
filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
joblib.dump(lr, filename)

filename = 'finalized_countvectorizer.sav'
joblib.dump(cvec, filename)

filename = 'finalized_tfidftransformer.sav'
joblib.dump(tfidf_transformer, filename)
```

## During testing

```
loaded_model = joblib.load("finalized_model.sav")
loaded_cvec = joblib.load("finalized_countvectorizer.sav")
loaded_tfidf_transformer = joblib.load("finalized_tfidftransformer.sav")

# Observe that I only use transform(), not fit_transform()
x_val_vec = loaded_cvec.transform(new_x)
X_val_tfidf = loaded_tfidf_transformer.transform(x_val_vec)

result = loaded_model.predict(X_val_tfidf)
```

Now you wont get that error.

## Recommendation:

You should use [TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) in place of both CountVectorizer and TfidfTransformer, so that you dont have to use two objects all the time.

And along with that you should use Pipeline to combine the two steps:- TfidfVectorizer and LogisticRegression, so that you only have to use a single object (which is easier to save and load and generic handling).

So edit the training part like this:

```
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
lr = LogisticRegression()
tfidf_lr_pipe = Pipeline([('tfidf', tfidf_vectorizer), ('lr', lr)])

# Internally your X_train will be automatically converted to tfidf 
# and that will be passed to lr
tfidf_lr_pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Similarly here only transform() will be called internally for tfidfvectorizer
# And that data will be passed to lr.predict()
y_preds = tfidf_lr_pipe.predict(x_test)

# Now you can save this pipeline alone (which will save all its internal parts)
filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
joblib.dump(tfidf_lr_pipe, filename)
```

During testing, do this:

```
loaded_pipe = joblib.load("finalized_model.sav")
result = loaded_model.predict(new_x)
```

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed answer i really appreciate it. Ive implemented pipeline which makes things easier to read and training and testing is working. I am currently loading the finished model into another script and inputting raw text and it is giving me predictions. Is this correct I dont need to countvectorize and tdidf anymore because of pipelining ?

Comment: @dmnte Yes. Those are already contained in the pipeline and hence saved. No need to save them separately

Answer (score 1):

You have not `fit` the CountVectorizer.

You should do like this..

```
cvec = CountVectorizer()
x_val_vec = cvec.fit_transform(new_x)
```

Similarly, `TfidTransformer` must be used like this..

```
X_val_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(x_val_vec)
```

Comment: thank you, now its saying 
"result = loaded_model.predict(X_val_tfidf)
AttributeError: 'CountVectorizer' object has no attribute 'predict'"

Comment: Are you sure the file `finalized_mode.sav` is the trained model.?. It is a saved `CountVectorizer` file accoring to the error. Make sure you are saving the trained LR model properly

Comment: Thank you i was saving it as countvectorizer. After fixing that and running it again i get the following error. "ValueError: X has 130 features per sample; expecting 223086". I am using only 1 model so am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: it says the model was trained on a dataset with different number of features.You are trying to predict the with different features. Try printing the shape of X you used to train the model and the X you are using to predict

Comment: The x shape for what im predicting is (12,129). For training the shape was (1197030, 223086) and I was able to predict using test set with (399011, 223086). The csv im reading from has one less column and alot less overall entries, is this why the shape is different ?

Comment: Yes. I assume you are using some text based features. Since your vocabulary is less the output made by the Vectorizers will be different. You can Vectorize both the train and test set the same time and later load it to make predictions.

Comment: the train and test set are the same size and work fine, its when i try to predict single entries from similar but different data. Is it possible to predict smalller entries ?

Comment: You have to use the same Vectorizers you used on the train set to vectorize the test sample. Otherwise it wont work as the feature numbers will be different

Comment: as far as i can tell I am, the training set used CountVectorizer.fit_transform and tfidf_transformer.fit_transform and the test set used the same but just transform. Now for prediction on the new data its using the same but fit_transform again,

Comment: the same error, that x doesn't have enough features per sample. The csv im reading from in the new data has a much smaller amount of entries compared to what I trained and tested with and as I add to it the amount of features grows but its never going to equal what i used for training. the code is here https://gist.github.com/ishikawa-rei/c5928cff3a410ed0046580aa64ec4bd3